# Get parent div recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion

I have this HTML

```
<div id="main-container">
   <div style="style-here" data-status="active" data-state="loaded">
      <div style="style-here">
         <div style="style-here" {{click_event}}></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="style-here" data-status="active" data-state="unloaded">
      <div style="style-here">
         <div style="style-here" {{click_event}}></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="style-here" data-status="inactive" data-state="unloaded">
     <div style="style-here">
         <div style="style-here" {{click_event}}></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

On click on one of the elements that has {{click_event}} I want to search recursively till I can find an element that has data-status or data-state, and in the worst case when I meet the id from top to stop de search.

The HTML is made generated from another JS file and I can't change the way is made it. Is there a way with `closest` or `parent` from `jQuery` to search after `data` attribute?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for recursion, you can use `closest()`:

```
$clickedElement.click(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).closest('[data-status], [data-state], #main-container');
});
```

Comment: I tried with closest but `div:data(status)`.Thank you Rory McCrossan.